# Sorting in Lucene treats word differently between upper and lower case?

Tags: sorting, lucene.net

I have the following code on sorting[1], but I ended up with a result set in which words begin with numeric placed first and then words in uppercase sorted ascendingly with words in lowercase sorted ascendingly at the bottom, like below [2].

Is this by design? If so how can I sort them without the case being taken into consideration?

[1]
`Searcher.Search(Query, null, 30, new Sort(new SortField("title", SortField.STRING)));`

[2]
[42bskfdj3434]
[Fast Five]
[Green Lantern]
[Kung Fu Panda]
[bob]
[laptop]
[xoom]
[yearn]

Answer (score 1):

Index the field "title" as ANALYZED and use an analyzer that lowercases the input text (eg, StandardAnalyzer)